# What are the known convex polyhedra with congruent faces?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, convex-geometry, polyhedra, classification

*Note:* I originally asked this question on math.SE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3888486/what-are-the-known-convex-polyhedra-with-congruent-faces), where I posted a bounty on the question but received no answers after a week despite apparent interest in the problem. I'm hoping MathOverflow may have a better knowledge of the literature here.

---

A *monohedral* polyhedron is one whose faces are all congruent.

We have a classification of all convex isohedral (face-transitive) polyhedra, consisting of 30 classes of assorted finite polyhedra and infinite families. See [Wolfram Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Isohedron.html) for a list.

In the process of writing [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3886678/), I was trying to find instances of convex polyhedra which are monohedral but not isohedral, and struggled to find a classification of such shapes or even a list of known instances with an outline of which cases remain open.

The instances I know of beyond the isohedral polyhedra given above:

- When the faces are regular polygons, the Johnson solids offer three non-isohedral examples: the [snub disphenoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snub_disphenoid), the [triaugmented triangular prism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triaugmented_triangular_prism), and the [gyroelongated square bipyramid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyroelongated_square_bipyramid).
- The [pseudo-deltoidal icositetrahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-deltoidal_icositetrahedron), the dual of the pseudorhombicuboctahedron. In footnote 46 on page 185 of *Advances in Discrete and Computational Geometry: Proceedings of the 1996 AMS-IMS-SIAM Joint Summer Research Conference, Discrete and Computational Geometry*, it is remarked that no other convex non-isohedral monohedra are known with non-triangular faces (or at least, none were known in 1996 - but see the next two bullet points). ([Here](https://books.google.com/books?id=vtkaCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA190&lpg=PA190&dq=%22monohedral%20polyhedra%22&source=bl&ots=g3uRanPNX-&sig=ACfU3U14093Sr_0qjAm10U4n9lXqc55HbA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjBuL_77d3sAhVeFTQIHTLqDosQ6AEwCHoECAgQAg#v=onepage&q=%22monohedral%20polyhedra%22&f=false) is a Google Books link to the relevant section of the previous source.)
- However, in a result apparently unknown to the above source, Ed Pegg provides what seems to be a counterexample in [this math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1667881/polyhedra-with-identical-faces); manually cutting out and folding the net, it does indeed seem to fold into a convex polyhedron.
- In the article [*The Bilinski Dodecahedron and Assorted Parallelohedra, Zonohedra, Monohedra, Isozonohedra, and Otherhedra*](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00283-010-9138-7) (Grünbaum, B., 2010), the author includes the [rhombic icosahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombic_icosahedron) and the [Belinski dodecahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinski_dodecahedron), and cites Belinski as proving that these are the only convex monohedra with centrally symmetric faces (such polyhedra termed *isozonohedra*) not already listed among the isohedra.
- In David Eppstein's paper [*On Polyhedral Realization with Isosceles Triangles*](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.00116) (link to arXiv abstract), three infinite families of convex monohedra not given above are listed, with isosceles triangle faces: one consisting of a heightened antiprism with pyramids glued to each large opposite face (called a "gyroelongated bipyramid"), a variant of the previous shape in which two halves are rotated about a skew hexagonal cross-section (called a "twisted gyroelongated bipyramid"), and a shape called the "biarc hull" which is related to a [sphericon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphericon). They cite the paper [*Some New Tilings of the Sphere with Congruent Triangles*](https://archive.bridgesmathart.org/2005/bridges2005-489.html) by Robert Dawson, most of which seem not to translate to monohedral polyhedra but which I haven't checked fully.
- The answers to [this math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2878041/solids-that-are-platonic-apart-from-faces-being-irregular-polyhedra), which provide monohedral polyhedra combinatorially equivalent to the icosahedron but with non-equilateral faces. (The scalene case is not always convex, but can be made so with small distortions to the angles of the triangles involved.) The book *Advances in Discrete and Computational Geometry* mentioned above goes into more detail about the possibility of such polyhedra.

Given the apparent lack of a classification of more restricted classes of polyhedra, I expect that no complete classification exists. However, I'd like to better understand the scope of which examples and impossibility results are known, as I haven't been able to find much in the way of a definitive source tackling this question. I'm hoping this question and its answers can at least serve as a better overview of known convex monohedra than the scattered state of information that seems to exist on the problem at present.

Comment: Just a link to a question of Wlodek Kuperberg, where he describes a polyhedron with congruent (isosceles triangle) facets: [Can the sphere be partitioned into small congruent cells?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/146763/6094). Also includes an image of one of [Dawson's beauties](https://mathoverflow.net/a/146781/6094).

Comment: The linked isosceles triangle polyhedron is the gyroelongated bipyramid of David Eppstein's paper (attributed to Michael Goldberg). Dawson's tiling of the sphere I think does not give rise to a monohedron, because some vertices lie on the line between two vertices of a triangle, so the line (in Euclidean space) between those vertices of the triangle will not lie on the boundary of the convex hull.