Polyhedra with equal faces
It is easy to see that for isosceles tetrahedra (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disphenoid) all faces are equal acute triangles. If we consider regular tetrahedra and attach a regular triangular pyramid to each face, then we obtain a polyhedron with equal triangular faces; each face will be an isosceles triangle with obtuse angle $< 120^{\circ}$.
For which other triangles there is a polyhedron with all faces equal to this triangle?
The same question for quadrangles (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezohedron for examples).

Take two identical pyramids with a regular polygonal base and stick the bases together.

But then we get a polyhedron, each face of which is an isosceles triangle with obtuse angle $<120^{\circ}$. We already have such an example.

Why would each face have an obtuse angle? The angles at the apex of a pyramid can be arbitrarily close to zero.

Yes, but for an arbitrary acute triangle we can construct an isosceles tetrahedra with faces equal to this triangle. The question is for which OTHER triangles we can construct a polyhedron with all faces equal to this triangle?

OK, we're on the same page now. Is there anything helpful at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376071/what-are-the-known-convex-polyhedra-with-congruent-faces

E.g., https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DisdyakisDodecahedron.html

Yes, but all faces of this polyhedron are also acute triangles.

OK, but there's a lot more at that mathoverflow page than that one polyhedron.
